# Cant visualize element value in the response (python requests)

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, browser-automation

I am scraping a web but I am in the last step really stack.
The problem is that in the browser I can see the element and its value.
This is the code in the browser, the sessionId element value is shown in the browser as you can see.
But when I use python with get request I can see every element and its values except that element.

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="mjf1dtjVyE6RWzwN56p5HfXWJDBwsWyAOvU0i4aCxOjm2ZXlUNYR_LeGUQ7HLuiTrLE1DdGUv6qmUP8e6Zf4C-MMyJITyERblm63DTOwdJRcLJTR5dzm4E5v3yusDi9TLGbDp670GvJOZhOU9dJEgeXbl2352wu4SsdOeMWaQ1WZmsJ9QJw=">
<input type="hidden" name="sessionId" data-savepayment-session-id="" value="2cdd73d7-a479-40dc-bcf7-5eeeaf3aee3c">
```

This is my python code:

```
    form = soup.find("form",{"class":"submit-order"})
    link = form.get('action')
    token = form.find("input",{"name":"csrf_token"}).get('value')
    session_id = form.find("input",{"name":"sessionId"}).get('value')
    inputs = form.findAll('input')
    print(inputs)
```

This is the output with my python code:

```
[<input name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="_tbpVfO-tGp7YRuZorQ2RzlQuAnUV7bmKwrcyXXa4_VxFJ5eFHHVmcu81RS6ZOZ7ROJiGRwS6eb_aWZ0qFyhhrKbfRdKdq5C9TWbk-i2r9UBcgInm8qwCOOpZ99yxIJQy79xMcfZ_OHdrQGmlFNWXUtn781zBN59LO_opzkFWxlO0OFQtfc="/>,
 <input data-savepayment-session-id="" name="sessionId" type="hidden" value=""/>]
```

As you can see the value for the sessionId is empty
Can you help me? I dont understand why I can see the value in the browser and not with my code.
Of course I am using request.session() and headers and posts.

this is an example of post

```
post2 = session.post(link, data=payload, headers = headers)
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64520644/cant-scrape-the-value-of-a-certain-field-from-a-webpage-using-requests

Comment: IT was that thank you so much! @Jonas